# In Ruby or Rails, what is the best way to convert Eastern Time to UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, utc

I'm not referring to

```
myDateTime = DateTime.now
myDateTime.new_offset(Rational(0, 24))
```

or

```
Time.now.utc
```

What I have is a text date is given in Eastern Time.

I can convert that text date into a DateTime. Let's call it `eastern_date_time`.

Now, we have a variable containing an DateTime, but nothing knows it's eastern besides us. Converting it ourselves would be quite onerous. If the date in Daylight Savings Time (DST) (March 8 to November 1st this year), we'd have to add 4 hours to our eastern_date_time var to get UTC, and if the date is in Standard Time (ST) we'd have to add 5 hours to our eastern_date_time variable.

How can we specify that what we have is an Eastern DateTime, and then convert it to UTC... something that will determine if the date is in the DST/ST, and apply the 4 or 5 hours properly?

I want to convert any sort of date I get into UTC, for storage in my database.

**EDIT:**

Using `in_time_zone', I'm unable to convert my Eastern Text Time to UTC. How can I achieve that objective? For example...

```
text_time = "Nov 27, 2015 4:30 PM" #given as Eastern
myEasternDateTime = DateTime.parse text_time # => Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:30:00 +0000 
#now we need to specify that this myEasternDateTime is in fact eastern. However, it's our default UTC. If we use in_time_zone, it just converts the date at UTC to Eastern
myEasternDateTime.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') # => Fri, 27 Nov 2015 11:30:00 EST -05:00 
myEasternDateTime.utc # => Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:30:00 +0000
```

That's not what we want. We have to specify that myEasterDateTime is in fact eastern... so that when we do a `myEasterDateTime.utc` on 16:30:00 we end up getting 20:30:00.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it like this with the help of the time zone suggestions.

```
time_text_1 = "Apr 20, 2015 4:30PM" #Scraped as an Eastern Time, with no offset of -5:00 from UTC included
time_text_2 = "Nov 20, 2015 4:30PM" #Scraped as an Eastern Time, with no offset of -5:00 from UTC included

Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
my_time_1 = Time.zone.parse time_text_1 # Output: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 16:30:00 EDT -04:00 
my_time_2 = Time.zone.parse time_text_2 # Output: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 16:30:00 EST -05:00 

my_time_1.utc # Output: 2015-04-20 20:30:00 UTC 
my_time_2.utc # Output: 2015-11-20 21:30:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 4):

There was a [`time_in_zone` method in the DateTime class](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone):

```
now.time_in_zone('UTC')
```

It has since been [renamed to `in_time_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Zones/in_time_zone):

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone('US/Pacific')
 => Wed, 22 Apr 2015 12:36:33 PDT -07:00
```

You can currently (2023 / Rails 7) get the list of all US zones via

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.collect(&:name)
```

or for another country:

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('ES')
```

Comment: where can I get a list of all the time zones such as 'US/Eastern'. Is there a command?

Comment: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect{|z| z.name }`

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to convert the Eastern Text Date to an Eastern Time, and then get the UTC equivalent with in_time_zone method. I've added an EDIT to the original post.

Comment: `myeasterndatetime.in_time_zone('utc')`

Comment: That doesn't accomplish the task. That sets our 4:30 PM time as UTC, meaning our variable now contains 16:30 UTC. Our text of 4:30 PM was given to us in Eastern Time. So our variable just contains "16:30 UTC". 4:30PM is "20:30 UTC".

Answer (score 1):

The objects of Time class have a method called `dst?` which basically tells you whether or not DST is applicable or not. So you can basically identify whether DST/ST is applicable and decide which to add - 4 or 5.

e.g. `Time.now.dst?`
If it returns true, add 4, otherwise add 5.

Comment: You can find further information here - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/dst%3F

Answer (score 1):

In the edited post, your string of time needs an offset from UTC.

**EDIT III:** Based on the comments (just having a string set to represent Eastern Time and needing to account for DST, etc.)

```
text_time = "Nov 27, 2015 4:30 PM"
the_offset = Time.zone_offset('EST') / (60*60)
eastern_time = DateTime.parse(text_time).change(offset: the_offset.to_s) # Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:30:00 -0500
eastern_time.utc # Fri, 27 Nov 2015 21:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: very close yes, it's just that the text being passed to me does not contain an offset. It's just a text date that is meant to be assumed ET.

Comment: Ok. Editing the answer to account for that

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't quite do the job either, as Eastern time is not always -5 from UTC (http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboututc.shtml - last sentence in last paragraph before image). During DST it is -4, but during ST it is -5. The only way I've been able to do it so far, is in the answer I posted to this original question, but it's not very clean. It's a couple of lines, but as you can see it handles the the DST's (Apr 20, 2015 for example) and the ST's (Nov 20, 2015 for example). Anyway I can clean it up?

Comment: Yeah ... not my style of code in that answer/response (just personal pref!!!). I'd just do this, `eastern_time = DateTime.parse(text_time).change(offset: Time.zone_offset('EST'))` to account for DST, etc.

Comment: That definitely looks better but doesn't appear to be working. It's giving off a datetime with +0000  as opposed to -5000

Comment: `eastern_time = DateTime.parse(text_time).change(offset: Time.zone_offset('EST'))` appears to be equal to `eastern_time = DateTime.parse(text_time)`

Comment: My bad! I totally spaced that it's in seconds (`zone_offset`, that is).

Comment: how would I change that. I did this, but it's still giving a ate of +0000 instead of -5000. `DateTime.parse(time_text_2).change(offset: (Time.zone_offset('EST')/60/60))`

Comment: Nice, nice. Just about there, lol. One last problem. Time.zone_offset('EST') returns the value based on TODAY's time. However, we want it based on the text we are being given. For example, "Apr 2015, 4:30 PM" is DST (-4), whereas "Nov 2015, 4:30 PM" is ST (-5). If we are given both of those dates today, and want them stored in our DB in UTC... we have a problem. TIME.zone_offset('EST') still always returns -5. We need the zone_offset from the text date passed in (Apr 20/Nov20), and not the current Time.

Comment: Given those constraints, I'd probably just use your own answer.